# Get __file__ of the IMPORTING file

Tags: python

Say there is a file tree of:

```
sample_module
  |___ file1.py
  |___ file2.py
```

How can I get `file2`'s `__file__`, from a function in `file1`?

`file1.py`:

```
def get_file_path():
    return __file__
```

`file2.py`

```
from sample_module.file1 import get_file_path
print(get_file_path())

# C:/.../sample_module/file1.py
```

How can I make it give me `C:/.../file2.py`?

I understand that the function `get_file_path` is saving the `__file__` into its namespace, and is not generating a new `__file__`. Is there a way to make `__file__` callable, or get the `__file__` at runtime?

---

Why I need it?

I have a library, with a logging module, that generates a logger.

I want the location of that logger to be e.g. 2 folders above file importing `generate_logger`.
I'd rather not the user have to specify `__file__` each time they want to use it.
Is there a better way?

i.e. in `mylibrary/logs.py`

```
def generate_logger(logname=__name__, level=logging.DEBUG, path=''):
    """Creates a logger instance. Set level of file handler.
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger(logname)
    if path == '':
        path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../logs'))
    fh = logging.FileHandler(f'{path}/{logname}.log')
    ## rest of logging code.
    return logger
```

-

```
 project
  |___ project
  |      |__ log
  |            |__ loads_generate_logger (code that does the import)
  |_______logs
            |_logname.log (creates a log folder 2 folders above where it was imported).
```

in `loads_generate_logger`

```
 from mylibrary import generate_logger()
 logger = generate_logger()
 # logger path = C:/.../venv/lib/site-packages/mylib-0.10/logs
```

Comment: And what if you import `file1` in 50 different files? Which one of the 50 paths should it output then? Are you really looking for the file where the function that calls `get_file_path()` is defined?

Comment: Yes, I want the caller of `get_file_path` to have it's `__file__`. So if it was called for 50 different files, it should return each of the 50 files' unique `__file__`

Comment: One way could be to pass in a reference to something that the module can get the file name from. Something like `sys.modules[__name__]`. But if you do that, you might as well get the name yourself and pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
import inspect

current_frame = inspect.currentframe()

current_frame.f_back.f_globals['__file__']
```

this will get the `__file__` global from the function that called your function

Comment: You should just be aware that if this is called for a non-main module, there's a chance that you'll get `something.pyc` instead of `something.py`

Comment: I'm actually getting this, `D:\Users\MyUserName\anaconda\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py`, which makes sense, because I'm using pycharm, and it does a lot of stuff in between... hmm this is much trickier than I thought.

Comment: Why don't you explain why you need it then, rather than asking how to make work your solution, where no one knows what the problem is. If know what the original problem is, people may have other suggestions.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I have updated the question, thanks for the suggestion.